# Custom bean instantiation logic in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application trying to use a rich domain model, with the following mapping in the Controller class:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/entity", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String create(@Valid Entity entity, BindingResult result, ModelMap modelMap) {
        if (entity== null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("An entity is required");
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            modelMap.addAttribute("entity", entity);
            return "entity/create";
        }
        entity.persist();
        return "redirect:/entity/" + entity.getId();
    }
```

Before this method gets executed, Spring uses `BeanUtils` to instantiate a new `Entity` and populate its fields. It uses this:

```
  ...
  ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ctor);
  return ctor.newInstance(args);
```

Here's the problem:

My entities are Spring managed beans. The reason for this is to inject DAOs on them. Instead of calling `new`, I use `EntityFactory.createEntity()`. When they're retrieved from the database, I have an interceptor that overrides the

```
public Object instantiate(String entityName, EntityMode entityMode, Serializable id)
```

method and hooks the factories into that.

So the last piece of the puzzle missing here is **how to force Spring to use the factory** rather than its own BeanUtils reflective approach? Any suggestions for a clean solution?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@ModelAttribute`-annotated method to pre-populate the model with your bean. Then data binder will use that bean instead of instantiating the new one. However, this will affect all method of the controller.

```
@ModelAttribute
public Entity createEntity() { ... }
```