# Is it possible to inject a bean into a spring form bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I tried to do it 2 different ways, but neither way worked.

```
@Component  
public class EmailForm{
...
private QuestionDAO questionDAO;
...
@Autowired
public void setQuestionDAO(QuestionDAO questionDAO) {
    this.questionDAO = questionDAO;
}
...
```

Another way:

```
@Component  
public class EmailForm implements ApplicationContextAware {
...
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    this.questionDAO = (QuestionDAO)applicationContext.getBean("questionDAO");
}
...
```

Neither way results in questionDAO being injected

Form bean is populated by spring:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@Valid final EmailForm emailForm, BindingResult result, final Model model) {
```

Comment: Can you give more information about the error you're getting and show the code/annotations for the QuestionDAO class?

Answer (score 0):

The code `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)` is happening **after** the form is submitted, not before.  In other words, when you do a form submission (HTTP POST) from your Spring Form, it's *then* calling that submit() method.

To pass any objects to your JSP in Spring MVC, use a `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView` instance and call `addObject` on it.

Then you can actually use plain-old JSTL tags to display the object.  For example: `<c:out value="${standardizedAddress.streetLine}" />`

Answer (score 0):

I think he just wants to know how to auto-inject a spring managed bean into a form POJO that is passed in as a parameter to the controller's handling method. It's not being set -- so there is no "error" perse and doesn't have anything to do with adding objects to the model.

Edit: it looks like this was answered in another thread, here: [Custom bean instantiation logic in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560725/custom-bean-instantiation-logic-in-spring-mvc)